# Poisson-Approximation of Poisson-Binomial distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, poisson-distribution, binomial-distribution

I'm looking for a proof as to why the Poisson-Binomial distribution can be approximated by the Poisson distribution.

A Poisson-Binomial distribution is a sum of independent Bernoulli trials that are not necessarily identically distributed: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_binomial_distribution

There's a Poisson limit theorem on Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_limit_theorem) that gives me a solution for the binomial distribution.

The proof of the limit theorem starts with:  $\lim_{n \to \infty} {n\choose k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k} = \lim_{n \to \infty} {n\choose k} (\frac{\lambda}{n})^k (1- \frac{\lambda}{n})^{n-k}$.

It uses the fact that $ np = \lambda$ (n trials with possibility p) and therefore $ p = \frac{\lambda}{n} $ and works from that, showing that $\lambda$ works out as the Poisson parameter.
In the case of the Poisson-Binomial distribution, the expected value is: $\lambda = \sum_{i=1}^{n} p_i$, where $p_i$ are the probabilities for the different Bernoulli experiments.

I'm not sure how I can use $\lambda = \sum_{i=1}^{n} p_i$ in the proof from Wiki. Or is there an entirely different way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Cam%27s_theorem, linked from one of the pages you cite.

Comment: Don't know how I managed to miss that link, thanks for pointing it out. Much appreciated!